# Duvida sobre GIT e como usar um projeto existente no servidor?

Tags: php, mysql, git, gitlab

Atualmente estou adentrando no método git, e tenho gostado bastante da forma que o desenvolvimento flui. Porém me deparei com um problema. Eu tenho vários projetos que já estão em seus devidos servidores, enviados via `FTP` tradicional.

Criar o projeto do zero e fazer o deploy em uma pasta vazia foi tranquilo, mas quando há arquivos na pasta não estou conseguindo postar atualizações e nem copiar os arquivos para o meu projeto no GitLab.

A dúvida é como posso copiar os arquivos de um desses projetos para um projeto no GitLab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se já existe arquivos na pasta, crie um repositório vazio pelo gitLab e em seguida siga os passos abaixo:

```
cd pasta_projeto
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/seuUser/nomeDoProjeto.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Se entendi bem o `git remote add origin` vincula a pasta local ao projeto no gitLab, essa parte acredito já ter feito e acho que eu não tenha conseguido passar minha dúvida real. Estou com problemas para fazer o deploy em uma pasta no meu servidor, usando token de deploy, quando faço a conexão da erro, a primeiro falando que a pasta não está vazia, e outro erro que não acontece nada, mesmo atualizando os aquivos no projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi perfeitamente, mas se você quiser atualizar os arquivos após adicionados.

use o comando dentro da pasta principal do projeto

```
git pull origin master
```